# Parameter value didn't match expected type while querying with some clause

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query("select w from GroupChatHeartBeat w where w.gender=?1 AND w.Id in (?2) order by heartBeatTime DESC limit 1")
public Long findId(String gender,List<Long> participants);
```

I want to retrieve id of that participant who is available in a given list of participant based on gender. but i m getting below exceptions.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rest] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [4027291] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [4027291] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [4027291] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long]
```

Comment: what is the type of id in your *GroupChatHeartBeat* Entity?

Comment: There is no such JPQL keyword "LIMIT".

Comment: type of id is Long and i want to retrieve only one record that's why kept limit 1.... is there any alternate ??

Comment: As I already said. LIMIT is INVALID SYNTAX FOR JPQL. Spring has something called Pageable if you want to do paging.

Comment: @AsadAli Alternatively you can try findFirst or findTop if you are using spring data jpa for limit query. Chech this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result